# Open a modal window to display additional information

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to make a modal window (which I think is the name for a pop-up window) open when a user clicks on a link. This window will contain additional information.

Here's an example of an link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model[i].mMasterCard.mCardName, "DisplayCardDetails", "Card", new { @_cardId = Model[i].mMasterCard.mCardID }, new {@class = "@selected dialog"} )
```

You see that there's a css class added, it's because I have tried this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.dialog').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var dialog = $('<div style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body');
        dialog.load(url, {}, function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            alert("let's check it");
            dialog.dialog({
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    alert("This is hit!");
                    dialog.remove();
                }
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

In these lines the firt alert `"let's check it"` is sprung, but never the second alert.

Which calls the following action in one of my controllers:

```
public ActionResult DisplayCardDetails(int? _cardId)
{
    if (_cardId == null)
    {
        TempData[MessageDomain.Tags.TEMPDATA_MESSAGE_ERROR] = NODATAFOUND;

        return RedirectToAction("DisplayCardsResults");
    }

    if (_cardId == 0)
    {
        TempData[MessageDomain.Tags.TEMPDATA_MESSAGE_ERROR] = NODATAFOUND;

        return RedirectToAction("DisplayCardsResults");
    }

    CardDisplay cardToDisplay = mCardManager.GetCardDisplayByID((int)_cardId);

    if (cardToDisplay == null)
    {
        TempData[MessageDomain.Tags.TEMPDATA_MESSAGE_ERROR] = NODATAFOUND;

        return RedirectToAction("DisplayCardsResults");
    }

    mCardItem = new CardItemPriceList
    {
        mCard = cardToDisplay,
        mItemPriceLists = mPriceListManager.ListLatestPriceListsByCardId(cardToDisplay.mMasterCard.mCardID)
    };

    mPriceListManager.BuildCardItemsBestPrices(mCardItem);

    return PartialView(mCardItem);
}
```

And, finally, the partial view:

@using MvcMagicAdmin.Models
@using MvcMagicAdmin.Utilities.General
@model MvcMagicAdmin.Utilities.CardItemPriceList

```
@if (Model.mCard != null)
{
    {
        ViewBag.Title = Model.mCard.mMasterCard.mCardName + " - (" + Model.mCard.mMasterCard.mCardSet.mCardSetName + ")";
    }

    if (Model.mCard.mMasterCard.mCardFlagFace == CardInfo.FlagFaceValue.Normal)
    {
        <h2>@Model.mCard.mMasterCard.mCardName Details</h2>     
    }
    else
    {
        <h2>@Model.mCard.mMasterCard.mCardName \\ @Model.mCard.mChildCard.mCardName Details</h2>
    }

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditCard", new { _cardId = Model.mCard.mMasterCard.mCardID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "DisplayCardsResults")
    </p>
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div id="multiCardDisplay" class="formStyle">
            @{
                Html.RenderAction("CardDetailsPartial", "PartialViews", Model.mCard);
            }

            <div class="float-left baseFontSize">
                <p>
                    Highest Price:
                </p>
                <p>
                    Provider:
                </p>
                <p>
                    Middle Price:
                </p>
                <p>
                    Provider:
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lowest Price:
                </p>
                <p>
                    Provider: 
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="align-right baseFontSize bold">
                @if (Model.mCardHighestPrice != null)
                {
                    <p>Highest Price = @Model.mCardHighestPrice    </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>@Html.Label(ValueDomain.FIELD_UNAVAILABLE)</p>
                }
                @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.mCardHighestPriceProvider))
                {
                    <p>Provider: @Model.mCardHighestPriceProvider</p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>@Html.Label(ValueDomain.FIELD_UNAVAILABLE)</p>
                }
                @if (Model.mCardMiddlePrice != null)
                {
                    <p>Middle Price = @Model.mCardMiddlePrice    </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>@Html.Label(ValueDomain.FIELD_UNAVAILABLE)</p>
                }
                @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.mCardMiddlePriceProvider))
                {
                    <p>
                        Provider: @Model.mCardMiddlePriceProvider
                    </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.Label(ValueDomain.FIELD_UNAVAILABLE)
                }
                @if (Model.mCardLowestPrice != null)
                {
                    <p>
                        Lowest Price = @Model.mCardLowestPrice    
                    </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>@Html.Label(ValueDomain.FIELD_UNAVAILABLE)</p>
                }
                @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.mCardLowestPriceProvider))
                {
                    <p>Provider: @Model.mCardLowestPriceProvider</p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>@Html.Label(ValueDomain.FIELD_UNAVAILABLE)</p>
                }
            </div>

            @if (Model.mItemPriceLists.Count > 0)
            {
                <label>
                    Lastest Price List for this card:
                </label>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Provider</th>
                        <th>@Html.ActionLink("Price Low", "ShowCardDetails", new { _sortOrder = ViewBag.LowSortParm } )</th>
                        <th>@Html.ActionLink("Price Mid", "ShowCardDetails", new { _sortOrder = ViewBag.MidSortParm } )</th>
                        <th>@Html.ActionLink("Price High", "ShowCardDetails", new { _sortOrder = ViewBag.HighSortParm } )</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.mItemPriceLists.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var className = i%2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";

                        <tr class="@className">
                            <td>@Html.ActionLink(Model.mItemPriceLists[i].mPriceListProvider.mPriceProviderName, "PriceProviderDetails", "PriceProvider", new { @_providerId = Model.mItemPriceLists[i].mPriceListProvider.mPriceProviderID}, null)</td>
                            <td>
                                @if (Model.mItemPriceLists[i].mPriceLow != 0.00m)
                                {
                                    @(Model.mItemPriceLists[i].mPriceLow != null ? Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item.mItemPriceLists[i].mPriceLow) : Html.Label(ValueDomain.NOPRICELISTYET))
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span>@ValueDomain.NOPRICELISTYET</span>
                                }
                            </td>   
                            <td>
                                @if (Model.mItemPriceLists[i].mPriceMid != 0.00m)
                                {
                                    @(Model.mItemPriceLists[i].mPriceMid != null ? Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item.mItemPriceLists[i].mPriceMid) : Html.Label(ValueDomain.NOPRICELISTYET))
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span>@ValueDomain.NOPRICELISTYET</span>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (Model.mItemPriceLists[i].mPriceHigh != 0.00m)
                                {
                                    @(Model.mItemPriceLists[i].mPriceHigh != null ? Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item.mItemPriceLists[i].mPriceHigh) : Html.Label(ValueDomain.NOPRICELISTYET))
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span>@ValueDomain.NOPRICELISTYET</span>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.mItemPriceLists[i].mPriceListDate)</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            }
            else
            {
                <span id="emptyMessage">There are no items that matches your search parameters. Please try again.</span><br/>
            }
            <div class="buttonField">
                <input type="submit" name="_submitButton" value="Get Latest Prices" style="width: 150px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <span id="emptyMessage">@MessageDomain.ERROR_PROCESSING</span><br/>
}
```

Although I know (through debugging) that the `DisplayCardDetails` method is called and successfully does its job, no windows are actually opened. I would need to first inform the user that the window is loading (because the action method takes a few seconds to load), and then open the pop-up window. I've been trying to do this for some time now and would really appreciate some good help on that.

*EDIT*

As a side-note, I'm debugging mainly with the latest Chrome.

Comment: have you confirmed that your callback is being hit? Either by debugging or putting a console.log inside the callback method?  Also, did you confirm that the dialog div is actually added to the body?

Comment: What is exacly the callback?

Comment: You're calling dialog.load, and supplying a callback:

    function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            dialog.dialog({
                close: function(event, ui) {
                    dialog.remove();
                }
            });
        }

Comment: I know that the `dialog.load` line is called. I will debug to check if the `close` function is hit.

Comment: What you really want, is to make sure the dialog.dialog(...) line is hit.

Comment: I have just debugged, I can say that the `dialog.load` line is hit, but it does not enter the `dialog.dialog` lines.

Comment: Another thing, the `dialog` div is NOT appended to the body. Maybe that's the reason why?

Comment: Yes, that's probably why, you should change var dialog = $('<div style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body'); to var dialog = $('<div style="display:none"></div>').appendTo(document.body);

Comment: I will try this and get you back on the results.

Comment: Nope, I have tried replacing the line, with no further results.

Comment: Did the dialog at least show up in the DOM?  Could you possibly point me to an example of your problem?